# Check the code coverage for a project on sonar with rest api

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Sonar version : 5.3

I am making this call

```
https://mysonar/api/resources/index?metrics=coverage&key=test-project
```

However , I am not getting the coverage of test-project from this call. 
But I am getting rest of the projects and their coverages.
When I just do this

```
https://sonaraws.kdc.capitalone.com/api/resources/index
```

I am able to see my test-project on the api response.

How do I drill down to a specific project and not check the other projects from the rest call to Sonar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `api/resources` doesn't support the `key` parameter. You have to specify project id by using `qualifiers` and `resource` parameters.

This should work for you:

```
https://mysonar/api/resources/index?metrics=coverage&qualifiers=TRK&resource=test-project
```

---

Available values of the `qualifiers` parameter:

- VW: view
- SVW: sub-view
- TRK: project
- BRC: module
- UTS: unit test
- DIR: directory
- FIL: file
- DEV: developer

Answer (score 6):

I am using the below api for fetching coverage. Sonarqube version - 6.7.5

Get the componentId for a project using first api listed below.

```
https://sonarurl/api/components/show?key=ProjectKey

https://sonarurl/api/measures/component?componentId=Ahvhjvds87373&metricKeys=coverage
```

Response

```
{
    "component": {
        "id": "Ahvhjvds87373",
        "key": "ProjectKey",
        "name": "ProjectName",
        "qualifier": "TRK",
        "measures": [{
            "metric": "coverage",
            "value": "79.3",
            "periods": [{
                "index": 1,
                "value": "0.0"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: A single request by simply using `?component=ProjectKey` instead of `?componentId=`  works form me... ex: `https://sonarurl/api/measures/component?component=ProjectKey&metricKeys=coverage`  https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/measures/component

Answer (score 0):

Version 9.9 of SonarQube does not have api/resources.  I used other answers from this post instead:

curl -u squ_***********************: "https://sonarqube.company.com/api/measures/component?component=&metricKeys=coverage&branch=" | jq

For this curl to work, the URL needs to be in "" otherwise Linux thinks & means run this in background.

Getting code coverage data this way is useful in case you want to get an alert when code coverage does not meet your need.  Though there should be a way to check if the project/branch passes quality gate but I have not looked into it.